# How to fix error found when loading /etc/profile: user/share/modules/int/sh line 36 and 61?

Tags: 18.04, error-handling

When I start my Ubuntu 18.04 or switch user, an error message pops up:

```
" Error found when loading /etc/profile:

/usr/share/modules/init/sh: line 36: /usr/bin/tclsh: No such file or directory
/usr/share/modules/int/sh: line 61: export: module: not a function

As a result the session will not be configured correctly, you should fix the problemas soon as feasable."
```

If anyone could suggest how to tackle this issue, that would be great!

Comment: I now tried sudo apt install tcl